# Extract image resources from Mac's builtin applications

Tags: xcode, macos, ui-design

Just an example, Apple's Mail, Notes and Messages use the same image for their "Edit" button. However, I cannot find that image in any of the `resources` folder in their app bundles. I guess the image might be in a system folder that is used by these applications. There are many "common used images" like this one that are not in Xcode's media library. Since they are already familiar to the users, it makes sense to use the same image set in my own app.

My question is, where can I find those images? A side question, is it legal to use them?

[image]

Comment: it should be inside Show Package Contents >   Contents > Resource of Application.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I cannot find them in the `resources` folder of their app bundles

Comment: As Akhil said, just right-click the Application.app file and select "Show Package Contents". You probably have to shoe the symbol bar to have the search field available. Enter .tiff for all TIFF resources, .png for PNGs or .pdf for PDFs. Apple tends to using pdfs nowadays. You should find what you are looking for as long as its not a programmatically rendered graphic.